# Elasticsearch query all documents where keyword value is greater than X [7.2]

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to find all documents that have a name that is over 32 characters in length.

This is the mapping of the document.

```
export const boards = {
  handle: {
    type: "text"
  },
  name: {
    type: "keyword"
  },
};
```

I tried to use painless to query the `size` of the field but the following query did not return any results despite the fact that there are.

**Query**

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : {
        "script" : {
          "script" : {
            "source": "doc['name'].size() > 32",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am thinking that it is perhaps related to the keyword type being used.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out from [this forum post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/scripted-fields-string-length-not-so-painless/198315) that when using keyword size is not the correct method. Instead you need to use:
`.value.length()` making my final query look like the following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : {
        "script" : {
          "script" : {
            "source": "doc['name'].value.length() > 32",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```